# Ring in which Jacobson Radical is different from nil radical

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Define $ Jac(R) = \cap_{\mathfrak{m}, maximal } \mathfrak{m}$ and $Nil(R) = \cap_{\mathfrak{p}, prime} \mathfrak{p}$, where $R$ is a commutative ring. Can someone give me an example of a commutative ring $R$ such that $Jac(R) \ne Nil(R)$. I have ruled out $\mathbb{Z}_{n}, \mathbb{Z}$, and any Artinian ring. Should I be looking at polynomial rings of some sort?

Comment: I found this duplicate by searching “Jacobson nil radical different”.  You should try something similar first, next time, before posting.

Comment: Could you explain why $Nil(R) = \{0\}$, where $R = F[[x]]$ for some field $F$?

Comment: A nilpotent element in an integral domain must be zero. Otherwise, it would be a zero divisor.